# zurb foundation make column width persist across screen sizes without individual declarations

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation, multiple-columns, grid-layout

Using zurb foundation, I'm looking to have a single class declaration that will persist across media query breakpoints. For instance, if I wanted to create a div that was 10 columns no matter if it were being viewed on a desktop or a phone.

I realize this can be accomplished by adding all classes like this:

```
<div class"xxlarge-12 xlarge-12 large-12...">
   The content  
</div>
```

**but**
I would really rather not add 5+ classes to every div that I want spanning the entire screen regardless of size.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Im actually currently running it with sass but I feel like there is a baked-in solution to this that I'm just not aware of. I would prefer to use "built-in" components if at all possible. If I'm wrong, and nothing exists, I may very well be custom-classing my way out of it.

Comment: As the answers below allude to, Foundation is built with a "mobile first" mentality. The small grid cascades up. Setting it with small will persist up the width dimensions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Foundation uses min-width media queries, which means as long as you're using the "small" class, and the it doesn't change as the screen gets larger that's all you need.

For example if you want it to be full screen on Mobile and half screen on desktop you would use the following markup:

```
<div class="small-12 large-6 columns"></div>
```

[Here's a link to the Zurb Foundation documentation on their grid.](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/grid.html)

Comment: At the risk of asking a nested question here, it seems:  `<div class="small-12">Content</div>`  and `<div class="small-12 columns">Content</div>` do almost the same thing. Is the "column" class vital to function correctly?

Comment: Looks like "columns" floats everything to the left. Which wouldn't be necessary if it's just 1 full width column. If it's multiple columns you would want to add it so that they are next to each other instead of on top of each other.

Answer (score 2):

If you use `small-4` it should scale all larger screen sizes to only take up `4` of the grid.

In your instance you want to use `small-12 columns`.